# always return empty rdd when integrating kafka with spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, rdd

I'm using Spark Streaming 1.5.2 + Kafka

```
object Kafka2HDFS {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka2HDFS")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))

    val zk = "192.168.1.105:2181,192.168.1.106:2181,192.168.1.107:2181"
    val topicMap = Map("online_dev" -> 2)

    val ds = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zk, "group_online_dev", topicMap)
    ds.map(_._2).window(Seconds(15)).foreachRDD(rdd => LogUtil.log.info(rdd.count()))

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

There are some json strings in kafka topic **online_dev**, They can be consumed with console-consumer. After the app is submitted, the zookeeper will contains following struct:

```
group_online_dev
  `- owner
      `- online_dev
         `- 1
          - 2
...
```

There's no **offsets** directory under group directory.

My Problem is, the RDDs returned in each time windows, are all empty.

In the log file, I found all **rdd.count()** is *0*.

I didn't use sbt assembly to package all jars in package for faster compile and deploy. Here is my submit script:

```
~/spark-1.5.2/bin/spark-submit --executor-memory 30g\
  --driver-memory 40g\
  --executor-cores 10\
  --num-executors 4\
  --name Streaming\
  --class dog.streaming.Kafka2HDFS\
  --deploy-mode cluster\
  --files "/home/hadoop/spark-1.5.2-t3-n/conf/hive-site.xml"\
  --master yarn\
  --driver-java-options "-XX:MaxPermSize=1G"\
  --jars "lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar,lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,lib/ImpalaJDBC4.jar,lib/play-functional_2.10-2.2.1.jar,lib/play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar,lib/play-datacommons_2.10-2.2.1.jar,lib/play-json_2.10-2.2.1.jar,lib/spark-core_2.10-1.5.2.jar,lib/spark-hive_2.10-1.5.2.jar,lib/spark-sql_2.10-1.5.2.jar,lib/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.5.2.jar,lib/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar,lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar,lib/zkclient-0.7.jar"\
  task/target/scala-2.10/jobs_2.10-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar problem. Just be sure to use
`"auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest"` property in your consumer kafka config.

See [official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ):

> **Consumers**
> Why does my consumer never get any data?
>
> By default, when a
> consumer is started for the very first time, it ignores all existing
> data in a topic and will only consume new data coming in after the
> consumer is started. If this is the case, try sending some more data
> after the consumer is started. Alternatively, you can configure the
> consumer by setting auto.offset.reset to "earliest" for the new
> consumer in 0.9 and "smallest" for the old consumer.